# SMS Forwarding in Android

Tags: sms, dual-sim

I use a dual SIM Android phone.
Model: **Micromax canvas 4** **Android OS version :4.2**

In this device, I have 2 SIM Cards, from two different carriers/operators. 
The issue is one of the SIM is flawed and looses connectivity often, sometimes when I am expected to receive SMS, at that very moment, I lose connectivity.

Hence, I want to forward this SMS to another SIM in same phone!

I already use Call forwarding on this device and it works perfectly fine, meaning if my SIM-1 looses connectivity, and someone calls on it, I still get the call on SIM-2, via call forwarding.

Is this possible with SMS?